# RAW socket and NF_INET_POST_ROUTING

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, netfilter

Is there a way to know in `NF_INET_POST_ROUTING` if the packet is generated via RAW socket:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, int protocol);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can use the [`type`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/include/linux/net.h#L114) field of `struct socket`.

F.e.:

```
static unsigned int nfh_handler(...) {
    struct iphdr *ip_header = ip_hdr(skb);
    if(ip_header->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP) {
        struct tcphdr *tcp_header = tcp_hdr(skb);
        if(skb->sk && skb->sk->sk_socket &&
            skb->sk->sk_socket->type == SOCK_RAW)
            printk(KERN_INFO "SOCK_RAW -> src port:%d, dst port:%d\n",
                   ntohs(tcp_header->source), ntohs(tcp_header->dest));
    }
    // ...    
    // return
}
```

Keep in mind that forwarded packets also could appear in `NF_INET_POST_ROUTING` hooks.